# What is difference between open development and open source?

Tags: osgi, adobe, aem, open-source, jcr

I know there are some questions about difference between Open Source Software and Free Software, but I do not understand if Free Software means the same as Open Development Software.

While reading Adobe's documentation on Granite platform I've found next sentence (in bold):

> Granite is a general purpose platform for building robust scalable
>   applications; it supports "open architecture", which is based on both
>   "open standards" (JCR and OSGi) and "open source" (Apache Sling and
>   Apache Jackrabbit). ... **Granite is open development, but not open
>   source.**

I do not understand last sentence. What means "open development"? It makes sense that it means that everyone can contribute to code, but is it then also an "open source" project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Adobe AEM teams we work a lot on Apache projects. As we like the Apache way we tried to apply the same project management principles to our internal closed source projects.

The key principles are "power to those who do" and "community over code". The result is kind of a shared responsibility for the projects. Everyone can participate in development of all code bases. You start by reporting bugs and improvement requests but you can also provide the solution in form of pull requests. If you do good work you are usually also allowed to do commits yourself and drive the direction of the project.

At Adobe this development style works very well as people are used to the Apache way. If you want to apply this in other companies be careful. A big part of the success is to establish the culture which is not guaranteed to work and takes a lot of time and effort.

Comment: That is open development then? If I understood correctly, if I am not Adobe's developer, I can not contribute to that code in any way? That is why it is not considered an open source project?

Comment: Open development is just a project management philosophy. It can be applied to open source as well as closed source. In case of the granite project it is not open source. Most of AEM is open source at Apache though .. see the Apache Sling, Apache OAK and Apache Felix projects.

Answer (score 2):

You can find what Adobe's "Open Development" means by going through [this conversation article](https://medium.com/adobetech/open-development-vs-inner-source-fdccf573a242) posted on medium.

If I understand it correctly, "Open Development" is more like [InnerSource](http://innersourcecommons.org/) but where the information and communications are shared outside the organisation as well.